# Rockmongo on Openshift not displaying inserted data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift, rockmongo

I have a `Node.js/MongoDB` application deployed on `Openshift`. I can fetch and save data into the database from the application but `Rockmongo` cartridge shows that I have no documents inside my `MongoDB` database.

I tried removing the `Rockmongo` cartridge and reinstalling it again, but the issue still persists. What might be the issue?

Comment: Are you able to ssh into your gear and use the command line mongodb commands to view the data in your mongodb database?

Comment: I did not try SSH but I am sure that the data is present in the database as I am able to retrieve it in my application.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Your database (that is used by the application) is not listed at all when you are logged in via RockMongo as admin, or only some collections are missing? You can also ssh into your app and check `~/app-root/logs/rockmongo.log` and `mongodb.log` if there's anything suspicious.

Comment: The database is listed and so is the collection. But it is empty without any documents in it.